# Add picklist to community based form using lightning data service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, picklist, lightning-data-service, lightning-recordeditform

I've got two fields on a Contact that I want to ask on a separate page with some verbiage on it and for some reason, I cannot get any of the LDS record handlers to work properly. I thought I would be able to use lightning:recordEditForm and just drop in the two fields but it gives me the error 'Assertion Failed!: Provider type not supported' as soon as a field is present within the form tags. No fields, no errors. Add the fields, the component doesnt load.

```
<aura:component controller="ApplicantHistory_RelatedListController">
<aura:attribute name="applicant" type="object" access="private"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<lightning:card title="Gender &amp; Ethnicity Survey">

    <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">

        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="contactRecord"
                                  recordId="{!v.applicant.userContact.Id}"
                                  objectApiName="Contact"
                                  recordTypeId="{!v.applicant.userContact.RecordTypeId}">            


        </lightning:recordEditForm>         


        <!--

        <lightning:inputField fieldName="{!Ethnicity__c }" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="{!Gender__c }" />
        -->


    </div>
</lightning:card>

</aura:component>
```

The above works / loads, when the picklist fields are commented out. When I add them back into the form is when it fails.

The goal is to have extra verbiage around these fields, making it clear about the use of gender and ethnicity, seems like thats semi-sensitive data these days. Those two fields are picklists, so I want to pull the values from the Contact and show the picklists here. This, I thought, wouldve been the best way to do this. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `lightning:inputField`tags have to be nested within the `lightning:recordEditForm` tags.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="contactRecord"
                          recordId="{!v.applicant.userContact.Id}"
                          objectApiName="Contact"
                          recordTypeId="{!v.applicant.userContact.RecordTypeId}">            

    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Ethnicity__c" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Gender__c " />

</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

and your fieldname should only be the api name of the field (no data binding):

```
{!Ethnicity__c} => Ethnicity__c
```

Comment: Shortly after I posted this, I realized I was using the wrong notation inside the fieldname attribute. thanks for your answer!

Comment: no worries, keep at it =)